Can't align things the way I want
Currently trying to create something kind of like a about me page, I'm currently having some issues aligning things properly.
My current issue is, neither of the bottom boxes as shown in the pic don't seem to align the way I want.

Here is a visual example of what I am trying to achieve.
I honestly don't know what to do which is why I am asking here.


.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;

}

#nick {
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 63%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7);
  color: gold;
  border-color: #B2B2F9;
}

.huge {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 40px;
  gap: 40PX;
}

.leleft {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.ni {
  border: 4px double ;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7);
  color: #B2B2F9;
  border-color: white;
}

.leright {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 850px;
}

.purpose {
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7);
  color: #B2B2F9;
  border-color: white;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
<div class="top">
    <h1 id="nick">sdasd</h1>
</div>
<div class="huge">
    <div class="leleft">
        <div class="ni">
        <h2>es</h2>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        esss
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leright">
    <div class="purpose">
    <h2>asdasd</h2>
    <HR>
    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eum assumenda neque deserunt atque. Sunt dolore et magnam numquam, error at sit laudantium fugiat consequuntur cum. Veniam tenetur error vel!</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eum assumenda neque deserunt atque. Sunt dolore et magnam numquam, error at sit laudantium fugiat consequuntur cum. Veniam tenetur error vel!</div>




Remove align-items: center; from huge to start.
Then apply flex:1 to .ni to make it expand to the full height


.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#nick {
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 63%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: gold;
  border-color: #B2B2F9;
}

.huge {
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 40px;
  gap: 40PX;
}

.leleft {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.ni {
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #B2B2F9;
  border-color: white;
  flex: 1;
}

.leright {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 850px;
}

.purpose {
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #B2B2F9;
  border-color: white;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
<div class="top">
  <h1 id="nick">sdasd</h1>
</div>
<div class="huge">
  <div class="leleft">
    <div class="ni">
      <h2>es</h2>
      <hr>
      <hr> esss
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="leright">
    <div class="purpose">
      <h2>asdasd</h2>
      <HR>
      <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eum assumenda neque deserunt atque. Sunt dolore et magnam numquam, error at sit laudantium fugiat consequuntur cum. Veniam tenetur error vel!</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eum assumenda neque deserunt atque. Sunt dolore et magnam numquam, error at sit laudantium fugiat consequuntur cum. Veniam tenetur error vel!</div>




THANK YOU SO MUCH. can you tell me why align items interfered with the positioning? I've always just added justify content align items to center things

.top {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 30px;
}

#nick {
   border: 4px double;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px 10px;
   width: 63%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   color: gold;
   border-color: #B2B2F9;
}

.huge {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   gap: 40px;
   margin-top: 40px;
}

.leleft,
.leright {
   width: 50%; /* both item will get half of the container size */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.ni,
.purpose {
   border: 4px double;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 5px 5px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   color: #B2B2F9;
   border-color: white;
   flex-grow: 1;
}



